# using onClick in a table row that also has links in it

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using onClick in table rows as follows:

```
<tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="http://www.whatever.com/index.php?var={$foo1}">
```

I also have some needs to put a link in certain areas in this table row, i.e.

```
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td><a href="specialLink.php?var={$foo2}">Here</a></td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
```

The problem is, the "inner link" (specialLink.php) can't be clicked, because the row link takes precedence.   Do I have any options here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I 'll do that :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var link=true;
</script>

<tr onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onclick="if (link) window.location ='http://www.whatever.com'">

<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
<td onmouseover="link=false;" onmouseout="link=true;"><a href="specialLink.php">Here</a></td>
<td>Stuff Here</td>
```

Comment: using this, when I click the link nothing happens.  If I click in other cells on that row, it correctly goes to the main link.  If I click using my mouse wheel (open in new tab) - it will open the correct link in the tab.   Any other ideas?

Comment: What browser are you using ? It works fine for me with FF and IE

Comment: I think this solution could be problematic on touch screens.

Answer (score 7):

You can use stopImmediatePropagation() to bypass consecutive/incoming events.

Short example:

```
<tr onclick="alert('tr event')">
    <td>tr event</td>
    <td onclick="alert('td');event.stopImmediatePropagation();">NO tr event</td>
</tr>
```

Test this on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/g8Anh/6/

Comment: Important: using a function to control events, you MUST pass the [event] object

Comment: This worked for me. If you do inline javascript, you don't have to pass anything. You just use the above method.

Comment: This only works on IE >= 9. For most ie versions "event.cancelBubble=true;" works.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do this (and this utilizes [jQuery](http://jquery.com)):

```
$("td")
    .click(function(e){
        var tag = e.target.nodeName;
        if( tag === 'A' ){
            // link was clicked
        } else {
            // normal td was clicked
        }
    });
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/4n9AW/).

This replaces the need for even using inline Javascript.

Comment: Problem with this one is that I can only have one link.  I have 100's of rows of data and each one has a different link (parsed by PHP before it gets to here)...

Comment: You say you can have one link, but then you say that you have hundreds of them...?

Comment: Yea maybe I should have been more clear... I updated it (I use smarty, as you'll see).  Every ROW has a different value for $foo1 and $foo2

Comment: @Shackrock: This jQuery should work anyways. Give the example a try. There are multiple links in the tables, try clicking every cell.

Comment: See my answer below. You can do this with jQuery no matter how many cells you have.

Answer (score 3):

I would actually put an event on the entire table, not each row. Especially if you have hundreds. So...

```
<table id="links" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <tr data-var="{$foo1}">
        <td><a href="http://example.com/">Link</a></td>
        <td>Another cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('links').onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var t = e.srcElement || e.target;
        if( !t.tagName) t = t.parentNode; // some browsers treat text nodes as potential targets
        while( t != this) {
            if( t.tagName == "A") break;
            if( t.getAttribute("data-var"))
                location.href = "http://example.com/index.php?var="+t.getAttribute("data-var");
        }
    };
</script>
```

This method does not pollute the global scope, and uses a single event which is always more efficient than one per row.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting an id on the table cell and use jQuery to handle the click event. For example...

```
<tr id="row1">
    <td id="cell1" class="table_cell">etc</td>
    <td id="cell2" class="table_cell">etc</td>
</tr>
```

Your jQuery code can the trap each click via the table cell's class as follows...

```
$(".table_cell").click(function(){
    // Activated by a click on any table cell with the class "table_cell"
    var cell_id = $(this).attr("id"); // Loads id of td element clicked on
    // Insert code that deals with a click on that specific table cell here...
});
```

You might even try putting the URL in a title tag, retrieving it in a similar manner as I retrieve the id above, thus eliminating a lot of messy javascript and if/then code.

Using jQuery's .hover() you can also replace onmouseover and onmouseout out with a single jQuery function. This results in code that is shorter, cleaner and can be placed in an external .js file for easy use on any page you need it.

Answer (score 1):

on the td element surrounding your link put the following attr:

```
<td onclick="event.cancelBubble=true;">your link with event</td>
```

This is how we solve it for IE at my work

Comment: This worked for me on Firefox, Chrome, & Edge. Thank You!